# How to override core block class correctly? - Magento 1.x

Tags: magento-1.9, blocks, overriding

**1 way:** to copy directory structure of core block to local code pool and copy core block file. For example : `app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Navigation.php` to `app/code/local/Mage/Catalog/Block/Navigation.php`. And then and needed methods.

**2 way:** Configure rewrite in this way:

```
 <global>
    <blocks>
      <catalog>
        <rewrite>
          <navigation>Vendor_Catalog_Block_Navigation</navigation>
        </rewrite>
      </catalog>
    </blocks>
  </global>
```

And then extend my class from magento core class.

Which way is more correct?

Answer (score 0):

The second way is the correct one.

The first way is generally used if you have to correct a real Magento bug (and there is no patch available).

Finally, I would say that it is sometimes unnecessary to rewrite a block : you can create your own block (that extends the core one) and call yours in the layout declaration : `<block type="your_alias/navigation" ...`

Edit : I have to add that there is a difference between a `rewrite` (way 1) and an `override` (way 2). See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17105798/difference-between-override-and-rewrite-in-magento) . So, my answer is more adapted to the question "How to **rewrite** a core block correctly ?"...